# microsoft teams : escaping underscores in text posting to webhook

Tags: markdown, microsoft-teams

I am posting a list of Azure resource groups to a channel in teams using incoming webhook.

Some Azure resource groups have underscores in them, these are getting parsed and the text between two underscores is italicized. From the docs I could gather that it's Markdown behavior but I am unable to escape underscores using a `\` (backslash) similar to how you would do in Markdown.

What is the right way to post text with underscores such that its rendered correctly?

(Would be nice to know what variant of Markdown is being used.)

Sample payload:

```
{
  "text": "<br/><h1>Some text (some azure subscription id)</h1><br/>some text (more text): <br/>['resource_group_name_1', 'resource_group_name_2', 'resourcegroup-rg-foo-bar']<br/><br/>some text (more text): <br/>['resourcegroupname']<br/><br/>See <a href="https://someaccount.visualstudio.com/_git/reponame?path=%2FREADME.md">documentation</a> and <a href="https://someaccount.visualstudio.com/someproject/_build?definitionId=1234&_a=summary">sometext</a>."
}
```

`resourcegroup-rg-foo-bar` appears as is, but `resource_group_name_1` appears like resource*group*name1.

Comment: Similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302516/markdown-can-i-have-underscores-w-o-escaping-them-and-not-have-markdown-italic

Comment: Are you sending the azure resource groups json as a adaptive card with incoming webhook?

Comment: following this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-connectors (only setting "text" which is simple html)

Comment: Could you please share the message card json?

Comment: updated question with sample

Comment: @dparker, FYI, HTML tags formatting is not supported in Message Card payload json. Please take a look at  [Message Card](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: Using Message Card worked. Though the value of the "text" key is used as markdown, I am able to escape the underscores here using "\\". Appreciate the help!

Comment: It's mind-boggling they don't allow turning Markdown off for machine generated messages. This forces you to escape all the values.

Answer (score 5):

Disabling markdown at a section level is now supported in Cards. You can set `markdown` to false.

Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#office-365-connector-card)

**Example**

```
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
    "summary": "Office 365 Notification",
    "title": "Office 365 Service Degradations",
    "sections": [
        {
            "markdown": false,
            "facts": [
                {
                    "name": "Service Incident:",
                    "value": "ID"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Start time:",
                    "value": "check_disk_critical"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Service:",
                    "value": "SERVICENAME"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Description:",
                    "value": "MESSAGE"
                }
            ],
            "title": "Office 365 Service Problem"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I got same issue, Can anybody help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65923762/microsoft-teams-escaping-underscores-in-text

Answer (score 0):

It works with markdown set to false. No need to escape the underscores if you set markdown to false. Hope this helps