# Microsoft Teams escaping underscores in text

Tags: ruby, microsoft-teams, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have following function in ruby to send aws logs to microsoft team channel through webhook. Some text contains underscore signs like `connection_web` but appears like `connectionweb` in MS teams. How to get the exact output ?

```
require 'json'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
require 'base64'
require 'zlib'
require 'stringio'
def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  log_event = JSON.parse(decode_and_decompress(event["awslogs"]["data"]))
  response = speak(messages_from_blob(log_event))
  puts response.body
end
def speak(message)
  http = Net::HTTP.new("MS-Teamwebhook.com", 443)
  http.use_ssl = true
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(ENV["HOOK_URL"])
  request.body = JSON.generate({
    text: message
  })
  http.request(request)
end
def decode_and_decompress(input)
  binary_compressed = Base64.decode64(input)
  gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(binary_compressed))    
  gz.read
end
def messages_from_blob(event_data)
  event_data["logEvents"]
    .map{ |e| e["message"] }
    .join("\n")
end
```

Comment: It seems by default it turned on markdown flag, I turned off in code `markdown: false` but still having issue.

Comment: Anybody please help me to get rid off this issue ?

Comment: Hi @blaCkninJa, I am unable to repro the issue using postman, Could you please try [Sending messages to connectors and webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using).

Comment: Hi @blaCkninJa, Are you still facing the issue? if yes, would request you to try using postman by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#example-connector-message) document. It has sample examples

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT I have mentioned the details below. Issue not resolved using ruby code.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT can you update on this ?

Answer (score 0):

@Jagadeesh: I used following request using postman body and send the message passwd in `value` in last paragraph to msteam channel now the output received perfectly. But same message cannot received using above ruby code.

```
{
"@type": "MessageCard",
"@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
"summary": "Office 365 Notification",
"title": "Office 365 Service Degradations",
"sections": [
    {
        "markdown": false,
        "facts": [
            {
                "name": "Service Incident:",
                "value": "ID"
            },
            {
                "name": "Start time:",
                "value": "check_disk_critical"
            },
            {
                "name": "Service:",
                "value": "SERVICENAME"
            },
            {
                "name": "Description:",
                "value": "# Time: 210211  6:12:12
    # User@Host: live_test_demo_web[live_test_demo_web] @  [10.7.13.209]  Id: 468920921
    # Query_time: 2.070946  Lock_time: 0.000041 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 762480
    use web;
    SET timestamp=1613023932;
    UPDATE `testing_web`.`abc_customer_data` SET `test_processing`=0 WHERE `id` > 0;"
            }
        ],
        "title": "Office 365 Service Problem"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Hi @blaCkninJa, 
The payload/card JSON provided by you is working fine at our end. Teams does not escape underscore in any of text field in message cards. It looks like the issue is with the code on your end. 
Please trace and debug the application to find out where the escape of underscore happens. Also, doing a network capture for the request would also help as we can inspect the payload sent to the Webhook endpoint.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT I have fixed the issue by using messagecards with python script.

Answer (score 0):

We have raised a bug for this and concerned team is working on it.